# C# Linq Check if List of List is inside List of List

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two Lists of Lists:
(1) **variants**   and (2) **options**.

I need to see if ALL of options exists inside variants (regardless of order).

For Example: in the code below I need to make sure each list of items appears in the variants list - so the list "blue", "red" "green" must appear in the variants list regardless of order

**EDIT (clarification):**
All of the lists inside of "options" must appear in "variants". If one of them fails then the boolean must return false.

I setup a LINQ condition but I'm not sure why its not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 //TEST 1

    List<List<string>> variants = new List<List<string>>();
    variants.Add(new List<string> {"cars", "boats", "planes"});
    variants.Add(new List<string> {"money", "trees", "plants"});
    variants.Add(new List<string> {"green", "blue", "red" });
    variants.Add(new List<string> {"kid", "adult", "senior"});
    variants.Add(new List<string> {"tax", "insurance", "salary"});

    List<List<string>> options = new List<List<string>>();
    options.Add(new List<string> { "senior", "adult", "kid" });
    options.Add(new List<string> { "blue", "red", "green"});
    options.Add(new List<string> {"money", "trees", "plants"});

    bool exists = variants.Any(a => options.Any(b => b.SequenceEqual(a.OrderBy(x => x))));

    Console.WriteLine(exists);
    // The result should be TRUE even though the order of "senior", "adult" and "kid"
    // is different and that the order of listed items is different


 //TEST 2
    List<List<string>> options2 = new List<List<string>>();
    options2.Add(new List<string> { "senior", "adult", "kid" });
    options2.Add(new List<string> { "orange", "red", "green"});
    options2.Add(new List<string> {"money", "trees", "plants"});

    exists = variants.Any(a => options2.Any(b => b.SequenceEqual(a.OrderBy(x => x))));

    Console.WriteLine(exists);
    // The result should be FALSE. All listed options are TRUE except that the 2nd list has
    // "orange" which doesn't appear in the variants list.



 //TEST 3
    List<List<string>> options3 = new List<List<string>>();
    options3.Add(new List<string> { "senior", "red", "adult" });
    options3.Add(new List<string> { "blue", "kid", "green"});
    options3.Add(new List<string> {"money", "trees", "plants"});

    exists = variants.Any(a => options3.Any(b => b.SequenceEqual(a.OrderBy(x => x))));

    Console.WriteLine(exists);
    // The result should be FALSE. All of the items actually exist in the variant list, 
    // but "senior", "kid", and "adult" do not appear together within a list of variants.
```

Comment: You're only sorting the variant, not the option. As none of the options are in order, you'll get no matches. I'd suggest you use e.g. `HashSet<T>` and `SetEquals` here, as you really have sets rather than lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a `HashSet` for each variants list and then check for each options list at least one variant set contains all the options:

```
List<HashSet<string>> variantSets = variants.Select(vl => new HashSet<string>(vl)).ToList();

bool allIncluded = options.All(ol => variantSets.Any(vs => ol.All(vs.Contains)));
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rNS7Uc)

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: @bagofmilk Note that this will also work if there are more variants than options in a given set.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you use `HashSet<T>` rather than `List<T>` for the options / variants, as you have set semantics here rather than list semantics: options can only appear once & the order isn't important.

For example:

```cs
 var variants = new List<HashSet<string>>();
 variants.Add(new HashSet<string> {"cars", "boats", "planes"});
 variants.Add(new HashSet<string> {"money", "trees", "plants"});
 variants.Add(new HashSet<string> {"green", "blue", "red" });
 variants.Add(new HashSet<string> {"kid", "adult", "senior"});
 variants.Add(new HashSet<string> {"tax", "insurance", "salary"});
```

And your check is backwards: you want to check if all options match any of the variants. So you need to start with options. `HashSet<T>` has a method to check if the sets are equal, so you can use this:

```cs
bool exists = options.All(option => variants.Any(option.SetEquals));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works so far, but both lists should be sorted within the comparison.

before:

```
bool exists = variants.Any(a => options.Any(b => b.SequenceEqual(a.OrderBy(x => x))));
```

fixed:

```
bool exists = options.All(a => variants.Any(b => b.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(a.OrderBy(x => x))));
```

Comment: This is **sooooo** close to what I need - but I need the function to make sure all items of the list list exist - right now it only checks to see if 1 of them is true.

Comment: maybe with this one? :)
```bool exists = options.All(a => variants.Any(b => b.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(a.OrderBy(x => x))));```